# How to calculate multiple times and display each answer in the form

Tags: c#, winforms

How to calculate multiple times and display each answer in the Windows Form using C#? The Windows Form will only display one answer regardless of how many times I click the "calculate" button. How can I display all the answers, every time I click the button? Sorry if I ask a dummy question.
Below are my coding of calculation: `pert = (o + (4 * m) + p) / 6;`

```
 System.Windows.Forms.Label ans1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
 this.Controls.Add(ans1);
 ans1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
 ans1.Top = 400;
 ans1.Left = 300;
 ans1.Text = pert.ToString();
```

Comment: Each `Label` has the same `Top` and `Left`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, but you couldn't add more than one `Label` with the same name in any case. You'd need to generate your label names and pass them to a `AddValue` function (eg).

Comment: Add a [FLowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=net-5.0) to your form, then change `this.Controls.Add(ans1);` to `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ans1);`.  The code that sets `.Top` and `.Left` won't be necessary.  If you don't like the automatic layout, then you need to track how MANY labels you've added in a separate variable and change the `.Top` property to some kind of calculation like `.Top = numOfLabels * 40;`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overwriting the existing value each time.

I'd say you need to append the values. Your variable `pert` isn't defined in your code sample; I assume it is of type `DateTime`.

In which case, you need to do something like:

```
// To put the values on the same line with a comma/space separating them
ans1.Text += $"{pert}, ";

// To put the values on different lines
ans1.Text += $"{pert}\n";
```

**Tip**: You can also format the date/time if you wish using `ToString()` format modifiers such as:

```
pert.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -> 2020-11-30
pert.ToString("yy-MM-dd h:mm") -> 20-11-30 10:08
pert.ToString("F") -> Monday, 30 November 2020 10:08:45
```

More info on formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring).

**UPDATE**: It just occurred to me that you might be wanting to add a new `Label` control with a single value each time. In that case, you need to generate your labels and dispense with appending values to the same label:

```
this.Controls.Add(new Label()
{
    BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent,
    Top = top,
    Left = left,
    Text = $"{pert}"
});
```

You would need to modify either (or both) `top` or `left` to avoid overlaying controls on top of each other.

Comment: You may want to fix the missing {} when using string interpolation: `$"{pert.ToString()}, "`

Comment: @Dave Yes, fixed. Originally I had used `.ToString()` to allow formatting. Thx.